# Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, tvos

Recently I got the following error:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (13) must
>   be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the
>   update (12), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted
>   from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

The error occurs in the following code in my tvOS client:

```
 let removedIndexPaths = removedIndexes.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
 let addedIndexPaths = addedIndexes.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
 let updatedIndexPaths = updatedIndexes.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })

  self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
      self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: removedIndexPaths)
      self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: addedIndexPaths)
      }, completion: { _ in
          guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
              return
          }

          for indexPath in updatedIndexPaths {
              if let myCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell {
                  let item = self.dataManager.items[indexPath.row]
                  myCell.updateUI(item)
               }
          }

          let collectionViewLayout = self.collectionViewLayoutForNumberOfItems(self.dataManager.items.count)
          if collectionViewLayout.itemSize != self.collectionFlowLayout.itemSize {
                collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(collectionViewLayout, animated: false)
          }
  })
```

I am only using one section in my collection view:

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

I have checked out couple of posts on the same topic, but they have not solved my problem, my guess is that the problem is in the following two lines, but I am not sure:

```
 self.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: removedIndexPaths)
 self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: addedIndexPaths)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to [insertItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618097-insertitems) and [deleteItems(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618060-deleteitems) must be accompanied with change in the datasource as well.

So, before calling these APIs, you would want to change your datasource, i.e. add objects into it before calling `insertItems` and remove objects from it before calling `deleteItems`

Answer (score 1):

Found a very nice article about UICollectionView invalid number of items crash problem - https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2016/04/29/uicollectionview-invalid-number-of-items-crash-issue/

The item count returned by collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:) should be sync with the updates made inside the closure. With this idea in mind, it’s easy to solve, just add a property as the item count and update it inside performBatchUpdates closure

```
func updateItems(updates: [ItemUpdate]) {
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
  for update in updates {
      switch update {
      case .Add(let index):
          collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)])
          itemCount += 1
      case .Delete(let index):
          collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)])
          itemCount -= 1
      }
    }
  }, completion: nil)
}
```

and for the collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:), instead of returning items.count, we return the property which is manually maintained by performBatchUpdates closure.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemCount
}
```